# My Lucene search doesn't return results

Tags: java, lucene

I'm studying Lucene and this is my first test class. I'm trying to implement a in memory search and borrowed some codes from examples. But the search cannot return any hits. Can you help me with that please? Thanks.

```
    package my.test;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharArraySet;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.PrefixQuery;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
    import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

    public class TestInMemorySearch {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Construct a RAMDirectory to hold the in-memory representation of the index.
        RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();

    try {
      // Make an writer to create the index
      IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_42, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_42, CharArraySet.EMPTY_SET));
      iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
      IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(idx, iwc);

      // Add some Document objects containing quotes
      writer.addDocument(createDocument("Theodore Roosevelt man", "It behooves every man to remember that the work of the "
          + "critic, is of altogether secondary importance, and that, " + "in the end, progress is accomplished by the man who does " + "things."));
      writer.addDocument(createDocument("Friedrich Hayek", "The case for individual freedom rests largely on the "
          + "recognition of the inevitable and universal ignorance " + "of all of us concerning a great many of the factors on "
          + "which the achievements of our ends and welfare depend."));
      writer.addDocument(createDocument("Ayn Rand", "There is nothing to take a man's freedom away from "
          + "him, save other men. To be free, a man must be free " + "of his brothers."));
      writer.addDocument(createDocument("Mohandas Gandhi", "Freedom is not worth having if it does not connote " + "freedom to err."));

      // Optimize and close the writer to finish building the index
      writer.close();
      // Build an IndexSearcher using the in-memory index
      SearcherManager mgr = new SearcherManager(idx, null);

      try {
        Document[] hits = search(mgr, "man", 100);
        for (Document doc : hits) {
          String title    = doc.get("title");
          String content  = doc.get("content");
          System.out.println("Found match:[Title]" + title + ", [Content]" + content);
        }

      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      // In this example we aren't really doing an I/O, so this
      // exception should never actually be thrown.
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Make a Document object with an un-indexed title field and an indexed
   * content field.
   */
  private static Document createDocument(String title, String content) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new StringField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("content", content, Field.Store.YES));

    return doc;
  }

  private static Document[] search(SearcherManager searchManager, String searchString, int maxResults) throws IOException {
    IndexSearcher searcher = null;
    try {
      // Build the query.
      String[] tokens = searchString.split("\\s+");
      BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
      for (String token : tokens) {
        query.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("title", token)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
        query.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("content", token)), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
      }

      searcher = searchManager.acquire();
      ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = searcher.search(query, maxResults).scoreDocs;
      Document[] documents = new Document[scoreDocs.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocs.length; i++) {
        documents[i] = searcher.doc(scoreDocs[i].doc);
      }
      return documents;
    } finally {
      if (searcher != null) {
        searchManager.release(searcher);
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to something as simple as possible and then build up. Use a single field, use a plain `IndexSearcher` instead of `SearcherManagar`. Form a simple `TermQuery` instead of a `BooleanQuery` of `PrefixQuery`s.

Comment: Thanks, I have finished these simple test. Just want to know why this one doesn't work.

Comment: If you want that answer, then you should indicate the most complex work that does still work and which exactly change makes is stop doing so.

Comment: Yes, I messed with different things when trying different Querys. Still thank you for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control Indexing a field in lucene 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564029/how-to-control-indexing-a-field-in-lucene-4-0)

Comment: Not a dupe because this is about a specific failure, not a how-to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[StringField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) seems an obvious choice, but it isn't what you want to use here.  You want [TextField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html).  `StringField` represents the field as a single token, essentially a keyword or identifier.  `TextField` analyzes and tokenizes the field for full-text searching.

Fixing it is as simple as changing, in your `search` method:

```
doc.add(new StringField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("content", content, Field.Store.YES));
```

to

```
doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new TextField("content", content, Field.Store.YES));
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I was trying to use everything so this got messed up.

Comment: One question still, I can search by 'Document[] hits = search(mgr, "theodore", 100);' now, but I cannot search by 'Document[] hits = search(mgr, "Theodore", 100);'. With the same above codes. Do you know why it's case sensitive? I meant I thought it should be the contrary, I should be able to search with 'T', not 't', right?

Comment: In the index, your terms are going through a `WhitespaceAnalyzer` (among other transformations), so the indexed terms are all lowercased.  When using a `QueryParser`, the same transformation will be applied by it, generally, so searching will be case-insensitive.  However, when manually constructing TermQueries, you should make sure and lowercase your input first.

Comment: Yes, I found it. In StandardAnalyzer, they have: tok = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, tok); it converts everything to lowercase if I understand it right. :)