# How to control Indexing a field in lucene 4.0

Tags: lucene

Until Lucene version 3.9 , we could specify to index or not to index a field by using FIELD.INDEX.NO or FIELD.INDEX.ANALYZED etc. But in lucene 4.0 there is no constructor available, in which we may define this . How do we control indexing in this version?

I mean if i want a field "name" to be stored in index but doesn't want to index it, then how can i do it in lucene 4.0?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Constructors taking `Field.Index` arguments are available, but are deprecated in 4.0, and should not be used.  Instead, you should look to subclasses of `Field` to control how a field is indexed.

- [`StringField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html) is the standard un-analyzed indexed field.  The field is indexed is a single token.  It is appropriate things like identifiers, for which you only need to search for exact matches.
- [`TextField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/TextField.html) is the standard analyzed (and, of course, indexed) field, for textual content.  It is an appropriate choice for full-text searching.
- [`StoredField`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StoredField.html) is a stored field that is not indexed at all (and so, is not searchable).

Except `StoredField`, each of these can be passed a `Field.Store` value as a constructor argument, similar to Lucene 3.6.

For more information on this change, take a look at the [Lucene Migration Guide](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/MIGRATE.html), particularly the sections titled: "*Separate IndexableFieldType from Field instances*"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was helpful. One more thing that we can do is to create a new FieldType and set our requirements using the available methods, setIndexed(), setStored() etc. And then we can pass this fieldtype object to the field constructor.