# How to prevent a field from not analyzing in lucene

Tags: lucene

I want some fields like urls, to be indexed and stored but not to be analyzed. Field class had a constructor to do the same.

```
Field(String name, String value, Field.Store store, Field.Index index)
```

But this constructor has been deprecated since lucene 4 and it is suggested to use StringField or TextField objects. But they don't have any constructors to specify which field to be indexed. So can it be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control Indexing a field in lucene 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564029/how-to-control-indexing-a-field-in-lucene-4-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to index and store an un-analyzed field, as a single token, is to use `StringField`.  It is designed to handle atomic strings, like id numbers, urls, etc.  You can specify whether it is stored similarity to in Lucene 3.X

Such as:

```
new StringField("myUrl, "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042587/how-to-prevent-a-field-from-not-analyzing-in-lucene", Field.Store.YES)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you are totally right with what you are saying. With the new fields provided by Lucene you cannot achieve what you want. 
You can either continue using the Field as you described or implement your own field by implementing the interface [IndexableField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexableField.html). there you can decide yourself what behaviors you want your Field to have.

Comment: whenever something is deprecated there is always an alternate better way to do that. so i guess there should be something.

I could keep using it, but when a later version comes, this will be removed altogether and can problems later.

Comment: I read the of StringField documentation again and by default the StringField is not analyzed since it is not tokenized. It is indexed and stored as a single value as you want it. [StringField](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/StringField.html)

Comment: Keep in mind if you need more configurations that are less common you need to implement your own Fields or continue using the Field type. As you pointed out before. Implementing your own field is safer in case new versions are released.