# how to analyzed field for using apache lucene 4.0

Tags: lucene

I am using lucene 4.0 now i want to analyze field for using StringField.. Could Anyone tell me there is any way to to to analyzed String...

```
Document d = new Document(); 

d.add(new StringField("id_c", rs.getString("id_c"), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
d.add(new StringField("id_c",  Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
d.add(new StringField("name",   Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
d.add(new StringField("dob",   Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
d.add(new StringField("dep",   Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
d.add(new StringField("salary",  Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

how can i use Field.Index.ANALYZED this way .. any way to overcome this difficulties

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you take some examples and state what your queries look etc. StringField is a field that is indexed but not tokenized: the entire String value is indexed as a single token. For example this might be used for a 'country' field or an 'id' field, or any field that you intend to use for sorting or access through the field cache.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control Indexing a field in lucene 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564029/how-to-control-indexing-a-field-in-lucene-4-0)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564029/how-to-control-indexing-a-field-in-lucene-4-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Field.Index`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html) is deprecated, and should not be used in Lucene 4.X.  You should familiarize yourself with the subclasses of the [`Field`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html) class, and use the appropriate ones.  `StringField` is not analyzed, `TextField` is.  If you want an analyzed field containing textual content, you should use `TextField`.

Most of the time, one of the standard `Field` subclasses will provide what you need.  If not, you can pass a [`FieldType`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/FieldType.html) into the [`Field` constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#Field%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef,%20org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType%29) to customize how a field is indexed.

Also, generally, when you create a field and add it to a document, it should have a value provided as well, and only the first field you are adding actually provides a value.  So that will need to be seen to as well.