# When to use custom fields in Lucene

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I am working on building a search engine for building domain specific data using Lucene. Lucene is clearly powerful and customizable. Originally I created my own field types and was using those but then I was getting 0 hits so I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216817/my-lucene-search-doesnt-return-results) and found that I should use text fields. One of my fields is a date and another is a low cardinality category. I looked through the setters for `Field` and couldn't figure out what `StringField` and `TextField` implied and how I should look at them.  Should I use a custom field type for not strictly textual fields?

Comment: Which version of lucene do you use?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig 6.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TextField and StringField

The difference between `TextField` and `StringField` are hidden in the class `FieldType`. `FieldType` allows you to define fields with custom properties like this:

```
FieldType type = new FieldType();
type.setTokenized(true);
type.setStoreTermVectors(true);
...
document.add(new Field("fieldName", someString, type));
```

So, both classes extend from `Field` and set a different field type. This gets more confusing, since the field type differs depending on if the field is stored or not. (Source: Lucene 6.5 source code)

### When to use what

To make it short:

- Use `StringField` for information like IDs, URLs, etc. which won't require any tokening, stemming or other processing by some Analyzer.
- Use `TextField` for information which requires this processing, such as the title or the content of a document.
- For anything else which has to be stored in the index, use a `StoredField`.

## Numeric fields

Looking at the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html), we can see that besides the types `Field`, `StringField` and `TextField` lucene offers mostly numeric "Points". Points work like fields in the meaning that they are indexed, but not stored (see `StoredField` above for that).

For your date, I would recommend using a `LongPoint` to store a timestamp, e.g.:

```
document.add(new LongPoint("date", someCalendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000));
```

Using a point will later allow you to perform range queries using `LongPoint.newRangeQuery`, which can be used to retrieve the documents in a given time frame, or applied as an additional filter to an existing query.

Regarding your "low cardinality category", I'm not sure what you mean, but if it's a number you could use an `IntPoint`.